# jsPlumb is not defined

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I'm working with jsPlumb where I'm getting an error "jsPlumb is not defined". This is some of my code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           ;(function() {
               jsPlumb.ready(function() {
                   var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
                   //My code...
                   });   
               });      
           })();      
       });
    </script>
```

I think this error is because jsPlumb instance is in document.ready function 
I get the error occasionally.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just checking.. did you include the jsPlumb javascript file?

Comment: yes, i also working with JSF so i include like this: <h:outputScript library="js" name="jsPlumb.js"/>

Answer (score 0):

In your html do a

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/jsPlumb.js"></script>
```

and jsPlumb will be available